# Unknown type error trying to use the file method on sftp client from Paramiko in Python

Tags: python, file, ssh, sftp, paramiko

I'm using paramiko in Python in order to write files to linux servers. I seem to have errors when writing to a path which includes folders with Hebrew names. 
After initializing a ssh_client and sftp client on that session, i'm using chmod to get to the folder I want to write to. 
Then,
I'm using the sftp.file method to get a file object to write some content to.
It works when I have paths in English.
When I have a path that contains Hebrew the method fails.. 
It fails at the point I'm initializing the file in the sftp session.

The error is
Unknown type for u'/root/\u05e9/filename.json' type

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the error message "Unknown type", this error is not caused by initialization of the file object in your sftp session, but rather something afterwards has caused the error. It'll be clear if you can post the source code.

Comment: I cannot post the code sorry... I'm just wondering if there might be a problem with the library. The chmod to the library with the Hebrew name works. When I try using the sftp object it fails... I think the sftp might save the path when I'm using chmod and when trying to actually write to the path it fails because it savef the path in a different format or as a unicode which make Hebrew invalid...